# Updating SQL with multiple categories and checkbox (PHP)

Tags: php

I have table of category like this

Table Name : personality

```
 id | Category
  1 | cute
  2 | rich
  3 | stupid
  4 | funny
  5 | famous
```

All i want to do is make to check box option with php for this personality table and update other table with multiple category

and my form:

```
  <form>
    Name : <input name="user" type="text" id="user" value="<?php echo $line['user'];?>" />
    Personality : <?php $personality=mysql_query("select * from personality");
                  while($data=mysql_fetch_array($personality)){
                  $check = ($line['usr_char']==$data['category'])?"checked" : "";
                  <label for='$data[kategori]'>
                  <input type='checkbox' id='usr_char' checked value='$data[category]'>
                  <span class='custom checkbox $check'></span> $data[category]</label><br>}?>
```

How do I post the category of personality table into other table with multiple category?

Here is example for the result :
Table Name : people

```
  name | usr_char
  abby | cute,rich,funny
  andy | famous,funny
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one you are missing a name on the input element.

```
<input type='checkbox' id='usr_char' name='attribute[]' checked value='$data[category]'>
```

After that on the to get the value to update your people table with you would just use

```
$attributes = implode(",", $_POST["attribute"]);
```

Comment: works greattt, thank you very much, can you give me example for "for each command" to explode $attributes and post it to checked checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

Create another table called `people_personality`, with the following:

- `id` <-- your primary key
- `person_id` <-- your primary key from your "People" table
- `personality_id` <-- your primary key from your "Personality" table

Suppose you have in your `People` table:

```
id - name
1  - abby
2  - andy
```

Now you want to assign `abby` `cute`, `rich`, and `funny`:

```
INSERT INTO people_personality VALUES ('',1,1),('',1,2),('',1,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is **don't try to store multiple comma separated values in an SQL field**. It has many disadvantages including,

- Retrieving the individual values is a tedious process
- It is not readable
- Becomes difficult to maintain

So, instead use a [many-to-many link table.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804841/mysql-storing-multiple-value-in-single-column-from-another-table) For example, you can have tables this way:

**Table 1:**

```
Id | Category

 1 | cute
 2 | rich
 3 | stupid
 4 | funny
 5 | famous
```

**Table 2:**

```
Name | Usr_char

abby | cute
abby | rich
abby | funny
andy | famous
andy | funny
```

Having this way makes it easier for example, to add characters later and remove them and even to select them.

**To retrieve:**

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE Name = 'abby';
```

**To add:**

```
INSERT INTO table_name (Name, Usr_char) VALUES ('abby', 'cute');
```

Comment: where is the answer of `How do I post the category of personality table into other table with multiple category?`

Comment: @dianuj It is not a good idea to store multiple values in a single field. I don't think the OP's main problem is to find out a way to store multiple categories in the same field. Her problem is to get the job done in an `efficient` and `easy way`. Have a look at these answers : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4804841/mysql-storing-multiple-value-in-single-column-from-another-table
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973905/multiple-value-stored-in-single-coloumn-in-mysql-database?rq=1

Comment: I agree its not a good idea to store comma separated values but she is asking for  how to get these values for each user after form submits